# Is there any way to undo 'flutter clean'

Tags: flutter, dart

I did a stupid mistake unknowingly and now i've got like 1k+ errors after running the command `flutter clean`

Is there any way to undo this.

```
Deleting build...                                                  606ms
Deleting .dart_tool...                                              7.3s
Deleting .packages...                                               28ms
Deleting Generated.xcconfig...                                       3ms
Deleting flutter_export_environment.sh...                            1ms
Deleting .flutter-plugins-dependencies...                            1ms
Deleting .flutter-plugins...                                         1ms
```

Comment: Try running the code once. It'll create required meta data and download needed packages and the errors will be gone.

Answer (score 12):

Run `flutter pub get`, it'll reload the packages

Comment: Does this require internet ?

Comment: Not really required.

Comment: actually you do need internet.

Answer (score 3):

Just run `flutter pub get` and you'll be good to go.